# IMAP E-mail encoding issue

Tags: php, character-encoding, imap

I'm trying to parse e-mails with IMAP, i'm getting messages with `imap_fetchbody($conn, $i, 1)` which gives me:

```
string(566) "
The email message addressed to "hidden=2Esomething@site=2E=
net" with the subject "subject" has been successfully delivered to =
the destination at 12-Oct-2013 11:01 UTC=2E=20

This is an automated response=2E Please do not reply to this message=2E   Thank you=2E"
```

Now in above example, the `=2E` should be a `.` The header says the charset is `Windows-1252`.

I've tried `iconv` and `mb_convert_encoding` but both fail to resolve this.
Viewing the e-mail in the webmail client (roundcube) shows it as it should, but I can't seem to convert it properly.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Those characters are url encoded. Decode them.

Comment: As I was continuing to search, i found `quoted_printable_decode` in a comment at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchbody.php#111031 which solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was continuing to search, i found `quoted_printable_decode` in a comment at [PHP.net / imap_fetchbody](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchbody.php#111031) which solves the problem.